# BrowserId cookie in customsite vfpage submit

Tags: visualforce, cookies

I have a custom website with no user login, with form created in Visualforce page using vfpage compositions, after submit the page, it appears that sfdc creates a cookie called "BrowserId".

How can I tell sfdc not to create this cookie at all (can't even remove it with javascript).

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be helpful for you, but check Salesforce Full Privacy Policy Statement 
http://www.salesforce.com/company/privacy/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, as it is, it appears that sfdc allways tracks browser usage by default.  I'll make some tests to be sure if it is allways (customsites, raw vfpages, etc...)

Comment: @DannyRobles did you find anything conclusive on this?